# Create Choropleth Style Map in CartoDB programmatically

Tags: carto, cartocss, carto-js, choropleth, curl

I am trying to create a choropleth map for a school project I am working on. Based off user input, I will create a csv file that I will then upload to CartoDB using their Import API. By setting the create_vis=true option, CartoDB will automatically make a map using that table. By default, however, this map is of the Simple type. Is there any way to make this a choropleth type map programatically?

I understand that you can do this in the wizards editor in the UI, but I am trying to do all of this at runtime (so that it is dynamic).

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, what the Wizard does when you select choropleth is changing the CartoCSS properties of the layer. So first you have to create a CartoCSS style by categories/proportions and then set your layer to this style using `setCartoCSS()` method. You have three ways to achieve this, check [this tutorial](http://academy.cartodb.com/courses/cartodbjs-ground-up/basic-interactivity/#cartocss-strings-in-javascript) about how to do it.

Comment: Since I am doing this dynamically, the thresholds for the choropleth depend on the current data. How can I set appropriate thresholds depending on the data using setCartoCSS()? CartoDB seems to set these values for you depending on the data if you do it through the Wizard. Is there a way to do this programatically?

Comment: If what you want is to change the ranges/proportions of your choropleth map, you can create a layer selector (a dropdown menu, for instance). [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/8525229e34263adcaeaf) you have a working example about selecting different classification methods on a choropleth map. And [here](http://bl.ocks.org/oriolbx/8aa36a091ce32ae939ab156c13b2aa10) you have another about selecting different Torque styles.